# Is this script possible to run in google sites? Convert to appscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm pretty sure that google doesn't allow the javascript version of this code to run on google sites.... Is this code possible in appscript? What changes do I need to do? 
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/E8SyF/

```
var links = ["http://www.google.com/", "http://www.cnn.com/", "http://www.bbc.com/", "http://www.nbc.com/"];
var visited = [];
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
window.onload = function () {
    if (localStorage.clickcount >= 3) {
        document.getElementById('btn').className = 'maxques';
    }
};
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 0;
        }
        if (localStorage.clickcount == 2) {
            document.getElementById('btn').className = 'maxques';
        }
        if (localStorage.clickcount >= 3) {
            document.getElementById('btn').className = 'maxques';
            console.log(localStorage.clickcount);
            alert('You have completed this category');
            return;
        }
    }
    if (visited.length == 2) {
        document.getElementById('btn').className = 'maxques';
    }
    if (visited.length == 3) {
        alert('You have completed this category');
        return;
    }
    var random, url;

    do {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        url = links[random];
    } while (contains(visited, url));
    alert('Opening: ' + 'question ' + '#' + random);
    visited.push(url);

    var win = window.open(url, '_blank', "height=800,width=800");
    win.focus();
});

function contains(array, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == value) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Per guidelines, first post the apps script you wrote and what problems you encountered.

Comment: This is javascript. I want to know how to run it in google sites or what the App Script equivalent is.

Comment: Follow my previous advice before this gets closed

Comment: Apps Script HTML Service will give you the capability to create a website.  The code you presented can simply be put into a `<script>` tag in HTML.  I wouldn't even bother with Google Sites.  If you want a free domain name, use Google App Engine.  Sites has a lot of restrictions, and not much capability.  You can use HTML Service in Native mode to basically create a regular website for free.  It won't have a regular domain name, but if you use App Engine, you can get a domain name.  If you want complete control over your content, without the restrictions of Sites, that's the way to go.

Comment: I might try that route, but for reference purpose, once I put my javascript inside the html, how do I initiate it to run?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate you script ( javascript ) on the Google Sites with app engine.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1

You can download this Application , put your script in the cloub and communicate with your Google Sites.

You need to install python for you Computer

http://obtiva.com/blog/50-deploying-a-javascript-application-to-google-appengine-in-30-minutes